# Rails different headers for different pages with if statement, but headers persisting

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, layout, header

I wrote a simple if statement to change the headers depending on which page the user is on like so:

```
<% if @miscpage = true %>
  <%= render 'layouts/mischeader' %>
<% elsif @gallerypage = true %> 
  <%= render 'layouts/galleryhead' %>
<% elsif @photopage = true %>
  <%= render 'layouts/photoheader' %>
<% end %>
```

Then in the controller for the specific pages the @variable is set to true. The problem though is that the mischeader persists whenever I go to any other page. It's like the application layout is not resetting the rendering process.

I've tested this, by switching the order of the if statements above, and indeed if @photopage=true were evaluated first, it's the photoheader that would persist across all pages.

I've further tested by writing separate if statements like below, and indeed, now I get two headers after visiting both the miscpage and the photopage.

```
<% if @miscpage = true %>
  <%= render 'layouts/mischeader' %>
<% end %>

<% if @gallerypage = true %> 
  <%= render 'layouts/galleryhead' %>
<% end %>

<% if @photopage = true %>
  <%= render 'layouts/photoheader' %>
<% end %>
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need to compare the variables against `true` boolean in an `if` statement.  But for your case you are using assignment operator `=`, either change them to comparison operator `==` or get rid of the `= true` from all `if` and `elsif` statements.

Comment: Yes of course... man these easy ones keep hitting me. Digital beers for you!

Answer (score 0):

`x = true` is an assignment.  You are assigning true to x.  It will always succeed.  You want `x == true` to test equality.

`=` vs `==`